# Why are all my hosts installing a package defined for one host on the puppetmaster

Tags: puppet

I'm new to puppet and I'm trying to figure out how to get different hosts installing different packages, but I've stumbled upon an issue I can't figure out. These are my manifests:

**My `site.pp`:**

```
node default {
}

node 'debh3' inherits default {
}

node 'debh4' inherits default {
    import "db"
}

node 'master' inherits default {
}
```

**My `db.pp`:**

```
package { 'mysql-server':
    ensure => installed
}

service { 'mysql':
    ensure => true,
    enable => true,
    require => Package['mysql-server']
}
```

With this setup, `mysql-server` is being installed on `debh3`.

If I replace the "`import db`" with the actual code inside my `db.pp`, then `mysql-server` is only installed on `debh4` (which is the behaviour i'm after).

Does anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong here? I've put it all in `site.pp` to ensure there are no other dependencies affecting anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also note that the `import` statement is deprecated and about to be removed from Puppet `4.0`.

You should move your code to **modules**. In this case, you want to create a `db` module.

In `/etc/puppet/modules/db/manifests/install.pp`

```
class db::install {
    package { 'mysql-server':
        ensure => installed
    }
}
```

an in `/etc/puppet/modules/db/manifests/service.pp`

```
class db::service {
    include db::install
    service { 'mysql':
        ensure => true,
        enable => true,
        require => Class['db::install'],
    }
}
```

From you `node` block, you can then just

```
include db::install
include db::service
```

or even just include `db::service`.

You could have both resources in one class, but it's good practice to structure your code through multiple classes.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to determine the correct structure to get this working and classes looks to be it.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further digging, I found this in the "import" documentation at https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_import.html:

> Import statements have the following characteristics:
>
> They read the contents of the requested file(s) and add their code to top scope
>
> They are processed before any other code in the manifest is parsed
>
> They cannot be contained by conditional structures or node/class definitions
>
> These quirks mean the location of an import statement in a manifest does not matter.

This points to why what I was doing was incorrect and why it caused the behaviour. As for a solution, I will look into best practices and determine the "correct" way to structure my manifests.

Comment: This is not an answer - you should Edit your question to include your additional findings.

Comment: Apologies, I was still searching for a proper answer as to why what I was using was an incorrect approach. You answered my question a lot better than I, so I've accepted your response as the correct answer. Thank you!